# Using a series as input, how can I find rows with matching values in a pandas dataframe? e.g. df.loc[series]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df` and a series `s` matching the columns in `df`. I would like to find all rows in `df` that have the same values as `s`. I should probably mention that the columns can change, but `s` will always be a row within `df`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': {0: 0.015, 1: 0.02, 2: 0.025, 3: 0.015},
 'b': {0: True, 1: True, 2: True, 3: True},
 'c': {0: 'foo', 1: 'foo', 2: 'foo', 3: 'foo'},
 'd': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}})
s = df.loc[0]
```

The expected result in this case would be the return value of `df.loc[[0,3]]`. Alternatively, the index of the matching rows would do.

Of course, if the columns were the same everytime `df.loc[df['a']==s['a'], df['b']==s['b'], ...]` would work just fine. Maybe there is a way of generating the term within `df.loc[ ]` by means of some sort of comprehension?

I am imagining there must be a pythonic/pandas way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare rows by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and then test if all `True`s per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.eq(s).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
       a     b    c  d
0  0.015  True  foo  1
3  0.015  True  foo  1
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.eq(s))
       a     b     c     d
0   True  True  True  True
1  False  True  True  True
2  False  True  True  True
3   True  True  True  True

print (df.eq(s).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```